# what is the rate limit by SFCC/Demandware for OCAPIs?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities, demandware, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

Anyone here has any idea about what is the rate limit setup by SFCC/Demandware for OCAPIs. I am using **OCAPIs**(v19.10) with **Oauth** client having *grant_types* as *Business Manager*.

> (*urn:demandware:params:oauth:grant-type:client-id:dwsid:dwsecuretoken*)

. After that trying to search the orders and get a specific order. Its headers don't have that information as well. Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: There is section for quota in Business Manager 
Administration > Operations > Quota Status
Further the official this docs may help you https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2FDWAPI%2Fquota%2Fhtml%2Findex.html&resultof=%22%71%75%6f%74%61%22%20

Comment: It feels more of a demandware api limit, not OCAPI limit. Can I get one exact limit ? For e.g; LOM(also used by SFCC) apis give the exact limit in the http header in a call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no rate limit on OCAPIs but there are AM specific limits.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).